# gmock pointer to base class has no member gmock_

Tags: unit-testing, c++11, googlemock

Sorry if the title isn't clear.

I have a virtual base class:

```
class FileSystemInterface {
public:
    virtual ~FileSystemInterface() {};

    virtual void save(std::string file_content) = 0;
};
```

My mock class derives from this:

```
class MockFile : public FileSystemInterface
{
public:
    MOCK_METHOD1(save, void(std::string));
};
```

Now I have a method I'm testing that takes a unique pointer to `FileSystemInterface`:

```
void my_method(std::unique_ptr<FileSystemInterface>& interface)
```

My test code is as follows:

```
std::unique_ptr<FileSystemInterface> mockFile(new MockFile);
EXPECT_CALL(*mockFile, save(_));
my_method(mockFile);
```

The problem is that `EXPECT_CALL` gives me an error `class "FileSystemInterface" has no member "gmock_save"`

Presumably that is because my mock is a pointer to the base class, but if I change my test as follows:

```
std::unique_ptr<MockFile> mockFile(new MockFile);
EXPECT_CALL(*mockFile, save(_));
my_method(mockFile);
```

Then `EXPECT_CALL` is fine but now `my_method` complains: `a reference of type "std::unique_ptr<FileSystemInterface, std::default_delete<FileSystemInterface>> &" (not const-qualified) cannot be initialized with a value of type "std::unique_ptr<MockFile, std::default_delete<MockFile>>"`

How can I get around this conflict and create my test? Thank you.

**UPDATE**

As is pointed out in Alexey Guseynov answer, my method does take ownership of the pointer, so the thing to do was change my method to

```
void my_method(std::unique_ptr<FileSystemInterface> interface);
```

and run my test like this:

```
std::unique_ptr<MockFile> mockFile(new MockFile);
EXPECT_CALL(*mockFile, save(_));
my_method(std::move(mockFile));
```

Comment: My guess would be to use `std::unique_ptr<MockFile> mockFile(new MockFile);`. But then again, I have no experience with mocks in C++...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You must store the mock as MockFile, like this:

```
std::unique_ptr<MockFile> mockFile(new MockFile);  // not so obvious change
EXPECT_CALL(*mockFile, save(_));
my_method(mockFile);
```

But you need to change signature of your method. It is strange to take a reference to unique_ptr because it is not clear who owns the object. If my_method owns the mockFile, then transfer the ownership by moving the pointer in-to the method (pass it by value). If my_method does not own the file, then pass it as a plain pointer.

Comment: The not obvious thing @Alexey Guseynov's corrects in @dseiple's code is in his first line of code sample: use `std::unique_ptr<MockFile> ...`instead of `std::unique_ptr<FileSystemInterface> ...`