# Google Test Gmock - Mocking Class Templates, trouble on EXPECT_CALL

Tags: c++, unit-testing, googletest, googlemock

Trying to implement Unit tests for a Class Template with Gtest and Gmock, but having some troubles with EXPECT_CALL.

My Abstract Class:

```cpp
#pragma once

template <class T>
class AbstractMessageQueue {
   public:
    virtual ~AbstractMessageQueue() {}
    virtual T dequeue() = 0;
}
```

My MockClass: `mocks/MockMessageQueue.hpp`

```cpp
#include <gmock/gmock.h>
#include "AbstractMessageQueue.hpp"

template <class T>
class MockMessageQueue : public AbstractMessageQueue<T> {
   public:
    MockMessageQueue(){}
    ~MockMessageQueue(){}

    MOCK_METHOD(T, dequeue, (), (override));
}
```

My Test:

```cpp
#include <gmock/gmock.h>
#include <gtest/gtest.h>

#include "./mocks/MockMessageQueue.hpp"

using ::testing::StrictMock;

namespace my {
namespace project {
namespace {

class TestFixture : public ::testing::Test {
    public: 
       StrictMock<MockMessageQueue<int>> a{};
       AbstractMessageQueue<int>& queue = a ;
};

TEST_F(TestFixture, test1){
    
    EXPECT_CALL(queue, dequeue()).Times(1);  //!!ERROR error: ‘class AbstractMessageQueue<int>’ has no member named ‘gmock_dequeue’; did you mean ‘dequeue’? 
    
    queue.dequeue();

}

}}}
```

I get the following compilation error on the EXPECT_CALL line:
`error: ‘class AbstractMessageQueue<int>’ has no member named ‘gmock_dequeue’; did you mean ‘dequeue’?`

I cannot figure out what is the problem here. If I comment the line with `EXPECT_CALL` i can make the test compile, and it will fail because of:
`Uninteresting mock function call - returning default value.`
Which in my view means the Mock is indeed working and the failure is caused by the `StrickMock`

Can someone shine some light?
Thanks

Comment: Related/duplicates: [gmock pointer to base class has no member gmock_](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44028922/gmock-pointer-to-base-class-has-no-member-gmock), [google mock : error: ‘class ISInfo’ has no member named ‘gmock_registerCallBack’](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69971092/google-mock-error-class-isinfo-has-no-member-named-gmock-registercallback)

Comment: Why you've made this over-complicated? Why you've introduced this reference? https://godbolt.org/z/6fa3nsnbf

Answer (score 2):

`EXPECT_CALL` expects the mock object.

```
EXPECT_CALL(queue, dequeue()).Times(1);
```

should be

```
EXPECT_CALL(a, dequeue());
```

`.Times(1)` is odd and removed.

Comment: Thanks, man i spent 2 hours on this!!!!

Comment: `.Times(1)` is implicit, when not specified. It would be better to have something like `.WillOnce(Return(12));`